# P/invoking native c++ dlls in c# and providing different type parameters

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I was converting some managed C++ to c# code which needed me to p/invoke functions from quite a few dlls from other c++ projects. When you p/invoke these functions, you can specify the type of parameters to be different from what the C++ function expects. How does this run? Because this doesnt give a compiler error.
Ex: My C# pinvoked function provided a datetime parameter when the function expects an int paramter.

Comment: PInvoke doesn't give compilation errors, because the only information about the function is its PInvoke declaration - no h-files. If parameter types are different, but parameters have the same size, this may work. BTW, do you expect reply within 1 minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lie through your teeth in the [DllImport] declaration, there is very little that the pinvoke marshaller can do to detect that your declaration is a mismatch.  All that it knows is that there's a DLL file with a certain name that exports a function with a certain name.  It can't tell what arguments the function takes nor what it returns.  That requires better metadata for the function, the kind that a COM type library or .NET assembly metadata can provide.  No such metadata exists for a plain DLL, so it must assume that your declaration is accurate.

This is actually often very useful, it allows you to map, say, a void* to a byte[] or an IntPtr to a reference type reference or value type passed by ref.  And you can write overloads of the same function.

Intentionally getting it completely wrong, like hoping that a DateTime will be mapped to an *int*, can be diagnosed by a hard crash if you are lucky.  Like an AccessViolationException or a PInvokeStackImbalance.  No guarantee for that kind of luck however, it is just as likely to just generate garbage.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't give you a compiler error because it doesn't happen at compile time. The marshaller doesn't really have any information about the native method and types at compile time (other than the pinvoke signature) and therefore cannot help you.

Most pinvoke help pages on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s97shtze.aspx) state:

> P/Invoke provides little compile-time error reporting, is not type-safe

If you want to get a more nuanced and detailed understanding of p/invoke, then there's a plethora of articles and blogs posts you can find. Here are a few I recommend you read:

[CLR Inside Out: Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx)

[Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

[P/Invoke Revisited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163910.aspx)